# Wavemaker Service Variable HQL update foreign key column

Tags: hql, wavemaker

I have two tables employee, department with a one to many relationship such that a column name 'depRefID' in employee references the primary key of the 'department' table.

I have a dojogrid that fetched data from employee table via a Service variable and a select menu that lists the department names.

I've setup an onchange function on the select menu that, would ideally loop each selected row in the employee table and change its foreign key to the one selected via the select widget.

I'm trying to use a separate service variable to update "employee" table using and update query.

How can I reference or access the foreign key 'depRefID' in HQl as directly referencing it throws an exception.

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: You need to provide some information about your classes and how they are mapped. This is the whole point of using an ORM like Hibernate. Have you mapped your classes so that Hibernate can generate the proper SQL for you?